# "One hoped you were dead"

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronouns

In a scene in movie *Burnt*:

> Simone: Adam Jones. My God. One hoped you were dead.

It is the first time they see each other in a long time. Why does Simone say "one" as opposed to "Some hoped you were dead." I am trying to figure out if "one" is a generic reference here.

Comment: [correction: It is the first time they **have seen each other** in a long time.] Third person singular: he, she,it, one

Comment: @Lambie I am not quite clear on why "they see each other" doesn't work. Could you expand on that or point me to an existing answer?

Comment: @Lambie "simple present is for habitual actions." That can't possibly be the whole picture. I am pretty sure one can think of various examples where the simple present is used in many other situations. ["So our wedding festivities will be the first time they see each other in years and they are both being kind of squirrely about it."](https://www.nj.com/advice/2019/06/carolyn-hax-my-fiances-divorced-parents-hate-each-other-and-theyre-both-coming-to-our-wedding-help.html)

Comment: @Lambie 1. I would like to see a detailed answer because there are several things I am not clear on and which call for explanation, e.g. the line I just quoted. 2. I am describing a scene here. For the same reason fiction writing employs a lot of the past tense, but writing about fiction requires the simple present. It is _indeed_ the historical present. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present). **"Summaries of the narratives (plots) of works of fiction are conventionally presented using the present tense"**

Comment: @Lambie You seem frustrated, um... because I asked "why"? "You are asking a question about a text. That cannot be historical present." You sure about that? As a matter of fact what you suggested is also the present tense (perfect aspect). It is still within the scope of the narrative present. It is not the past tense, is it?

Comment: @Lambie You are making sweeping statements punctuated with directives and imperatives without ever trying to explain. "Just believe me." Is that not an imperative without an explanation? Is describing a one-time past event not a summary in its own right?

Comment: @Lambie So you are saying you are not happy that I am not accepting your explanation? I really think a fuller explanation/answer is needed. I still do. I don't believe you ever provided an explanation to the point I raise about your suggested grammar being the perfect aspect, or why summaries of single events are not summaries.

Comment: @Lambie Your explanation is simply "simple present is for habitual actions." Tell me which of these [published lines](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22first+time+we+see+each+other+in%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks) are describing habitual actions. Why do they have zero to do with your point? Because your explanation doesn't work with them? "First time we see each other in eight years and we start telling one another dreams and boyhood stories." "The first time we see each other in how long and is this what you want to say to me?" Curious how weird exactly Irene Watts or Theresa Tova sound to you.

Comment: Some random novel with some random dialogue is not proof of anything. Of course, authors deliberately use certain language to point to educational levels in their characters, if they themselves know it. But I would not expect much from a novel called "Locked and Loaded".

Comment: @Lambie But I didn't quote them as proof. That was part of my question regarding tense. Right from the beginning I asked for a fuller answer. FWIW, I also checked sentences in your suggested tense/aspect. Similar results.

Comment: You have a choice to make. Learn from what I have shared or continue to make comments. "It is the first time they see each other **in a long time**"is not grammatical. A non-habitual, one-off action with the expression "in a long time" (in ages, ) cannot take the present simple. And this is not googleable. Too advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"One", here means "I". It is a mainly British way of being formal. It is not used very often in informal situations, which makes me think that the Simone character is being humorous.

> one
>   pronoun (I/ME) ​ 
>   formal
>   the person speaking or writing:
>
> Of course, one (= I) would be delighted to dine with the Queen.

[One (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/one)

Comment: One of the things the British Royal family were famous for, about 50 years ago, was never using the word 'I'. They used to say 'one', as in "One was surprised to find an intruder in one's bedroom". That is different from the so-called 'Royal we', reserved exclusively for the sovereign as a formal way of saying 'I'. Queen Elizabeth II made a joke about that usage in her speech at a celebration of her wedding anniversary when, referring also to her husband,  she said ' We [pause] by which I mean both of us...'. it is now very old-fashioned to use 'one' in that sense, even if one is the Queen.